# combine two HU invariant moments

Tags: matlab

I have Gait recognition system. I am apply steps as in the paper "Gait Recognition Using GEI and AFDEI" using Matlab.

I found GEI and AFDEI then I found Hu 7 invariant moments for each of them.

For example for person 1 there is 6 GEI and 6 AFDEI then found invariant moments.

Now my question is

Who I combine these 2 invariant moments to get better recognition?

Comment: any help please? did I use sum? or what? I am try sum but it give me low result